# Open a message with Apps Script Gmail Add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I am doing a Gmail Add-on and I have a place where I show a list of messages with some condition but I need a way to open the message without leaving the active tab.

I have this item:

```
let action = CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('openMessage').setParameters({messageId: message.getId()})

CardService.newDecoratedText()
            .setTopLabel(truncate(message.getFrom(), 50))
            .setText(truncate(message.getSubject(), 100))
            .setStartIcon(CardService.newIconImage().setIcon(CardService.Icon.EMAIL))
            .setOnClickAction(action)
```

and the action is this:

```
const GMAIL_BASE_URL = "https://mail.google.com/mail/"

function openMessage(e) {
  const messageId = e.parameters.messageId;
  const userEmail = getProperty(USER_EMAIL_KEY)
  const messageLink = `${GMAIL_BASE_URL}?authuser=${userEmail}#inbox//${messageId}`
  
  return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
      .setOpenLink(
        CardService.newOpenLink().setUrl(messageLink)
          .setOpenAs(CardService.OpenAs.OVERLAY)
          .setOnClose(CardService.OnClose.NOTHING)
      )      
      .setStateChanged(true)
      .build();
}
```

This opens it on a new window or a new tab based on `setOpenAs` but what I need is to open it on the active tab.

Comment: Try displaying it in a dialog with htmlService